# Python linear independence using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How can I write a Python function that can takes n dimensional vectors and return boolean if vectors are linearly dependent? Can it be done using dot or do I need to write a full calculation?

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/412563/determine-if-vectors-are-linearly-independent

Answer (score 2):

You can check for the determinant of the matrix , if the determinant is zero then it's linearly dependent.

You can use the function `np.linalg.det(Mat)`

Comment: what if the number of vectors is not n?